# Compare Version number

Tags: c++

The following is the link to the problem I'm trying.

https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/compare-version-numbers/

I simulated the array to compare both the versions. But I couldn't find any mistake in the code.

```
//function that compare string A and string B
//and returns 1 or -1 or 0

int compareVersion(string A, string B) {
    //  vnum1 stores each numeric part of version A
    //  vnum2 stores each numeric part of version B
    int vnum1 = 0, vnum2 = 0;

    //  loop that runs until i and j less than lengths of A and B
    int i=0,j=0;

    while(i<A.length() || j<B.length())
    {
        //  storing numeric part of version A in vnum1

        while (i < A.length() && A[i] != '.')
        {
            vnum1 = vnum1 * 10 + (A[i] - '0');
            i++;
        }

        //  storing numeric part of version B in vnum2
        while (j < B.length() && B[j] != '.')
        {
            vnum2 = vnum2 * 10 + (B[j] - '0');
            j++;
        }

        //returns 1 if version A is greater than version B
        if (vnum1 > vnum2)
            return 1;

        //returns -1 if version B is greater than version A
        if (vnum2 > vnum1)
            return -1;

        //  if both are equal, reset variables and go for next numeric
        // part
        vnum1 = vnum2 = 0;
        i++;
        j++;
    }

    //returns 0 if both are equal
    return 0;
}
```

Input:
A = "4444371174137455"
B = "5.168"

Expected: 1
Actual: -1

Comment: use string comparison. No matter what int type you will use that will eventually overflow in some case.

Comment: @ThePhilomath right about overflow and string comparison, but I think for version comparison it's overkill

Comment: @P.Dmitry: yes its overkill in a production or real life scenario. But for competitive programming we must consider all scenarios.

Comment: @ThePhilomath Sorry, I skip a part, that it's code for competition, then you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an overflow. `4444371174137455` doesn't fit in `int`. Try to use `uint64_t` for `vnum1` and `vnum2`